# Add module to Debian's Apache2

Tags: apache-http-server, debian-wheezy

I am new to Debian, I want to add some modules to my Debian 7.7 Apache2. I add some using `a2enmod` command, but what I have to do when I want to enable a third part unlisted module? Do I have to do it by hand or there is some command that I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have to build your own .conf and .load file and enable/disable your module by `a2enmod`/`a2dismod`.